# Reading a Txt File into Python 3.5 with Korean and English characters in it

Tags: python, text, fonts, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to read a txt file with Korean and English in it.
Here is an **example:**
52:15   Greetings.  안녕하십니까.

**My code is:**

```
# Read a line and Split into tokens                                                                  
f = open(infile, 'r')
for line in f:
    if( matchObj = re.match( r"(\d\d:\d\d)\t([^\t]+)\t(.*)$", line )
        startTC, englishSubtitle, foreignSubtitle = matchObj.group(1), matchObj.group(2), matchObj.group(3)
    else:
        SyntaxError(line)
```

When I read it into python (3.5) on a 2012 Macbook Pro running El Capitan, I get the Error Message (at the bottom).

**Error Message:**

```
python3 *.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "txtToSrt.py", line 48, in <module>
readFileData( "Korean.txt" )
File "txtToSrt.py", line 26, in readFileData
for line in f:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Could you please suggest how to read this in.

Comment: `0xfe` - it can be [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems unfortunately Python has a problem with the Korean Won symbol.
Try the following to confirm this for python 3.5:

```
a_string = 'à'.encode ('utf-8')
print (a_string)

b_string = '₩'.encode ('utf-8')
print (b_string)

a_bytes = a_string.decode ('utf-8')
print (a_bytes)

b_bytes = b_string.decode ('utf-8')
print (b_bytes)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jacques.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line at the top:

```
import codecs
```

and changed the line to read the file as follows:

```
f = open(infile, 'r', encoding="utf-16")
```

Reading data works now, but writing to a file doesn't. The code to write is:

```
outfile = open("out.txt", 'w')
outfile.write( "{0}\n{1}\n".format(startTC, foreignSubtitle.encode("utf-16")) )
```

The output I get is:

```
01:00:01:16
b'\xff\xfe\x14\xbc\x98\xb0\x90\xc7'
```

I'd like the second line of the output to appear in Korean. How can I do this?
Thanks.